# refresh jquery data constantly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var scheduled = $("select").filter(function() {
return $(this).val() == "<%=pempidw%>";
});
document.write(scheduled.length);

</script>
```

and it is working with counting the amount of times a certain item is selected. however, it only works and counts properly if i refresh the page after options are changed. i need a way for this to constantly refresh or be "live" so if it was to auto refresh every second, everytime something is changed in the page it would reflect correctly.

I know how to do a full page autorefresh and no I don't want that.

Comment: What does `<%=` represent?  If that is server-side code, then this is never going to work.  Server-side code is rendered on the server before it's sent to the browser.  Otherwise, to manipulate the DOM without refreshing the page, you can use jQuery's `.text()` or `.html()` methods.

Comment: <%= is how you pull information for an asp page.

Comment: sparky- that you just made is counting how many times a select box is touched and clicked, and it is live. i need mine to be live just like that, however my page deals with 100's of dropdown boxes, and my code counts how many times "mercedes" was selected, or audi, etc.

Comment: and the code DOES work, it just doesnt update live. i have to refresh the page to get an accurate count number.

Comment: Server-side code is rendered on the server when it's sent to the page.   You cannot get new code from the server without refreshing the page or Ajax.

Comment: I've deleted my answer and you must follow this website's rules or any user has every right to flag and vote... that's just how SO works.   Please refrain from tantrums when you don't get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand.. if you just want the count to update (write) whenever something is clicked, why don't you just move the write:

```
$(".<%=pempidw%>-element").on('click', function () {
<%=pempidw%>Count++;
document.write(<%=pempidw%>Count);
});
```

also you may want to change the function to use [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of on.

Comment: i tried that and its not working. still not updating live unless i refresh the page

Comment: Try:  $(document).on('click', '.<%=pempidw%>-element', function () { console.log('clicked');});

Comment: so sorry. wrong code. i have updated i put the wrong code snippet there

Comment: in that case, all you need to do is wrap up the write code in the following: $('select').change(function(){ //write code });  but you should really specify / target the select with an id or class name. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/uv9shd7w/

Comment: not sure what you mean.  the document.write displays the # of times a certain item is selected in multiple dropdowns. and that works properly if you make selections, and refresh the page. so basically, i just need this code snippet to constantly refresh itself without refreshing the page.  we're not changing data that is selected, just counting

Comment: Why use `change` _instead of_ `on`?  Just use `.on('change'...` instead of `.on('click'...`.

Comment: no specific reason. If you check the docs, change is just a shortcut for .on('change'..